# Template methods in template class with the same template type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class and want to build a template method for the class with the same template type, It likes as following

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    void Set<T>(const T& t)  {...}  // I think this is wrong.

...
};


A<int> a;
a.Set<int>(10);
```

How to make it work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. Just use T: `void Set(const T& t) { }`. T will be whatever type your class was instantiated with. And use it normally: `A<int> a; a.Set(10);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. Within `A`, `T` is also defined, and that includes the definition of `Set`. So you would just say:

```
template< class T >
class A
{
public:
    void Set( const T& t ) {...}
};
```

If you wanted to template `Set` as well, so that different types can be used with it, you would do:

```
template< class T >
class A
{
public:
    template< typename U > void Set( const U& u ) {...}
};
```

Finally, note that sometimes when calling a *template function* you do not need to declare its template arguments *explicitly*. They will be *deduced* from the type of the argument you use to call them. *I.e.,*

```
template< typename T > void Set( const T& t ) {...}

Set( 4 ) // T deduced as int
Set( '0' ) // T deduced as char
Set<int>( '0' ) // T explicitly set to int, standard conversion from char to int applies
```

Comment: Instead of different names i.e. T and U I have given same name for both i.e. T and T (in place of U). But I am getting compile time error.What is the reason behind this.Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant member templates:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    template <typename U> void Set(const U& u)  {...}
};
```